# Select2 is not accepting new values after dynamically setting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Hi this is my first question a SO so please let me know if I'm not specific enough ;-)

I have a problem with **Select2** version *3.5.2*
I'm using the following line to set a value dynamically:

```js
$("#select2").select2('data', {id: "newId", text: "newValue"});
```

That line works perfectly but if I now want to change the value manually the **select2** field doesn't accept the new entered value. I first have to clear the field by using the **x** button or pressing the **del** key.

I have no clue what to do to be able to change the value without clearing the field first.

Thanks in advance for your support!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself after 2 days :-(
It was my fault. I was setting the data when the select2 field gets the focus.
After removing the set function in the select2-focus event everything works perfectly fine.

Here is a fiddler link if anyone is interested in what I was doing.
https://jsfiddle.net/7w7jqd11/19/

```
.on('select2-focus', function(e) { 
     validateField('select2');
 })
```

The validateField('select2') function was causing the error.

Thanks anyway and best regards to all of you!